# Determine the fixed field of a field of rational functions and its Galois group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $k$ be a field and $K=k(x)$ be the field of rational functions of $k(x)$. Let $\sigma $ and $\tau$ automorphisms of $K$ defined by $\sigma \left( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right) = \frac{f(\frac{1}{x})}{g(\frac{1}{x})}$ and $\tau \left( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right)= \frac{f(1-x)}{g(1-x)}$. Determine the fixed field $F=K^S$, where $S=\{\sigma, \tau\}$ and $Gal(K/F)$. Find an $h\in F$ such that $F=k(h)$.

The fixed field is defined as $K^S = \{x\in K \;|\; \alpha(x)=x  \; \; \forall\alpha \in S\}$, so, in this case I have that an element $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ belongs to the fixed field  iff $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f(1-x)}{g(1-x)}=\frac{f(\frac{1}{x})}{g(\frac{1}{x})}$, and then I literally don't have any clue of what to do. Any hint would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$\sigma$ and $\tau$ generate a group of order six. The images of $x$
under its six elements are
$$x,\quad\frac1x,\quad 1-x,\quad\frac1{1-x},\quad\frac{x-1}x,\quad\frac x{x-1}.$$
Any symmetric function of these is in the fixed field $F$.
The sum of their squares is
\begin{align}
x^2+(1-x)^2+\frac{1+(x-1)^2}{x^2}+\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^2}
&=\frac{H(x)}{x^2(1-x)^2}
\end{align}
for some degree $6$ polynomial $H$. Let $h=H(x)/(x^2(1-x)^2)$. Then $h\in F$
and $|k(x):k(h)|=6$ since $H$ has degree $6$. But $|k(x):F|$ must equal $6$,
so $F=k(h)$.

Warning: this might not work in characteristic two.

Comment: I am wondering about the element $\tau\sigma\tau:x\mapsto \frac{x}{1-x}$. Why isn't it an element of the Galois group? Furthermore, it seems to have infinite order, by my computations, $(\tau\sigma\tau)^n(x)=\frac{\frac{x}{1-nx}}{1-\frac{x}{1-nx}}=\frac{x}{1-nx}$.

Comment: @WyattKuehster $\tau\sigma\tau:x\mapsto\frac x{x-1}$ is an element of the Galois group, and has order $2$.